# pthread_cancel own implementation

Tags: c, operating-system

I have a task to try implement pthread_create. And I would like to realize similarity if pthread_cancel. When some thread call it, my func_cancel have to restore context of running thread.

I tried with getcontext() in thread and setcontext() in another thread as well as setjmp() + longjump()

```
// int ret = getcontext(thread_task->contex_before_call);
    // if (ret == CONTEXT_FAILED) {
    //     destroy_thread_task(thread_task);
    //     return KTHREAD_FAILURE;
    // }

    // or

    // setjmp(thread_task->thread_env);
```

but I faced with SIGSEGV when call longjump() or setcontext()

```
==160251== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==160251==    at 0x48AE20C: longjmp (longjmp.c:32)
==160251==    by 0x109972: main (main.c:48)
==160251== 
==160251== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x1ffefffdb8 --> 0xb2e09c74b45a520d
==160251==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=5557270052541410219 or greater
==160251== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==160251==    at 0x48AE311: __longjmp (__longjmp.S:104)
```

I researched that problem with stacks and suppose that setcontext and longjmp work with calling thread stack.

I want to achieve that this func calls from another thread

```
int kthread_cancel(kthread_t thread) {
    while (!thread->contexted) {
        sleep(2);
    }

    thread->canceled = 1;
    longjmp(thread->thread_env, 1);
}
```

Thread running in thread_func return to if statement

```
if (!thread_task->canceled) {
        thread_task->return_value = thread_task->thread_func(thread_task->thread_func_arg);
    } else {
        thread_task->return_value = KTHREAD_CANCELED;
    }
```

Comment: Thread cancellation is arguably more complicated than all the rest of the pthreads API put together; there are nasty race issues surrounding system calls which _production_ C libraries don't get right (the [glibc bug report for this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12683) has been open for _twelve years_ now); and there are strong arguments that it is a bad idea to have such an API at all (see [this discussion of the similar "TerminateThread" API on Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811) - note the first sentence). Are you sure you need it?

Comment: I honestly tried to read bug report and got main ideas. It is really complicated thing. Actually I thought about why I have to have function to cancel thread? I can't imagine situation where I need to use it. If some thread began doing bad things, I think cancellation is not good solution.And after cancellation I obviously will get nothing from this, only terminated thread, only freed resources, but expended effort exceeds usefulness.